# How can I find physical address of my files on hard disc

Tags: assembly, filesystems, ntfs, fat32

Suppose, I save a file on my hard disc drive(for example c:\abc.txt) that system file of my drive is in system file FAT32 or NTFS, I want to find physical address of this file for example sector number XXXXX to sector number yyyyy.
please help me.

Comment: You do realize that there might be many ranges if the file is fragmented?

Comment: yes, in these case I suppose all ranges are countinues

Comment: FAT or NTFS? In each case how to get the physical address is different.

Comment: If the file is fragmented I want to retrieve an array of sectors that save my file binaries

Comment: -1 for "I want you to write a program for me" attitude

Comment: NO, NO, NO... I want to how to... which function I can use and which source I must to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool you are looking for is called "nfi.exe" which is (used to be) part of the "oem support tools".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For FAT:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#Technical_design
- http://home.teleport.com/~brainy/fat32.htm

For NTFS:

- http://www.ntfs.com/

Comment: Thanks, But I want a program that do it for me, I don't know assembly language

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not going to do your work for you (mainly because I gotta do mine first). And you don't need assembly. C should be plenty. If you do at least give it a try, we can help.